# Problema Login con HttpPost

Tags: android

Hola Gente estoy desarrollando una app donde la parte login me genera error .. estoy haciendo la llamada con httpPost.. Cuando hago un debug veo que esta llegando mal la url se cambio con dos palabra , no se si es problema del servidor o el php...
ejemplo mi url ="htpp://xxxxxxxxx/apps/index.php"
cuando hago el debug lo veo asi....

url="POST http://xxxxxxxxxx/apps/index.php HTTP/1.1"

ahi es mi codigo..

```
@Override
           protected String doInBackground(String... voids) {
               String uname = voids[0];
               String pass = voids[1];


               InputStream is = null;

                   List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", uname));
                   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", pass));

                   try {
                       HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                       HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://xxxxxxxxx/apps/ce-app/index.php");


                       HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(newUrl);
                       httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                       HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost1);
                       HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                       is = entity.getContent();

                       BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
                       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                       String line = null;
                       while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                           sb.append(line + "\n");
                       }
                       result = sb.toString();

                   } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   } catch (IOException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }



               return null;
           }
```

Ahi esta el error

```
12-06 16:39:31.346 16104-16104/com.example.administrador.casaesp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.example.administrador.casaesp, PID: 16104
                                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at com.example.administrador.casaesp.Login$1LoginUsuario.onPostExecute(Login.java:159)
                                                                                   at com.example.administrador.casaesp.Login$1LoginUsuario.onPostExecute(Login.java:103)
                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:667)
                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:684)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Te genera error, ¿porque no agregar el error? es importante revisar el LogCat. Por cierto veo que usas clases de la library Apache que son obsoletas.

Comment: gracias @Jorgesys por su ayuda edite la pregunta con el error ..pero como la url viene mal seguro  por eso el resultado ,me devuelve null...

Comment: El error se produce en la clase Login.java, lo recomendable es primero probar la url, si puedes realizar una petición POST con los datos de "id" y "pass"

Comment: si lo probe en un browser y me devuelve el json que necesitaba.. pero cuanro lo corro por android me explota

Comment: Ok, si deseas desarrollar en Android es indispensable el LogCat, decir que te "explota" se puede deber a infinidad de causas, agrega el error que se presenta y tu clase Login.java :)

Comment: Gracias @Jorgesys lo logre a solucionar :)

Comment: agregue una respuesta , pero que problema es?

Answer (score 0):

`doInBackground()` debe obtener el valor de la petición , es una práctica incorrecta definir el valor de retorno como null:

```
@Override
           protected String doInBackground(String... voids) {
               ...
               ...  
               return null;
           }
```

Si obtienes un resultado debes retornar este resultado:

```
@Override
           protected String doInBackground(String... voids) {
               ...
               ...  
               result = sb.toString();

               return result;
           }
```

---

El problema indica:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String
>   java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference

Debes validar primeramente si el valor no es null para usar el método .trim() en la cadena:

```
 if(valor != null){
   valor = valor.trim();
 }
```